read mifare classic with pyscard using Dell ControlVault 3 contactless
I have Dell Latitude 5430, which has Dell ControlVault 3 contactless smart-card reader with NFC.
Here are its specs:
Dell Broadcom Smartcard Reader
In windows device manager, they appear as:

Using python's pyscard, I can already process a Desfire card:
from smartcard.scard import *

def select_reader():
    for reader in readers():
        print(reader)
        if reader.name == 'Broadcom Corp Contactless SmartCard 0':
            return reader

reader = select_reader()
cxnToCard = reader.createConnection()
cxnToCard.connect()
protocol = cxnToCard.component.getProtocol()
pcscprotocolheader = translateprotocolheader(protocol)
SCardTransmit(cxnToCard.component.hcard, pcscprotocolheader, [0x5A, 17, 17, 17])
SCardTransmit(cxnToCard.component.hcard, pcscprotocolheader, [0x71, 0, 0])
...

Until here, all is fine!
But when I want to process a NXP Mifare Classic 1k card, I have tried every thing but always seen the same result:
SW1: 0x6A SW2: 0x81

I have seen examples of commands like 0xFF 0x82 (load key to the reader), 0xFF 0x86 (authenticate), or others, but there is no way that I could get work any command to the Mifare.
I have also tried to transmit the same commands with:
cxnToCard.transmit

instead of SCardTransmit; I do not know if there is a difference, but the result is the same.
From specs it is seen that Mifare Classic 1k is supported!
Since I get always 0x6A 0x81, I am sure that I am missing some principle thing; I am using a wrong protocol, wrong command set, wrong command format, or whatever.
I also did not understand if this reader acts like pcsc or what. Also beside all searches, it was impossible to find any documentation for this reader.
What am I missing?
How can I process Mifare Classic 1k with this reader?
Where can I find any doc to see how to use this reader?

I wrote the code in C# using SCardTransmit and the commands you mentioned, first loading the key and then authenticating for the block I wanted to read or write.
I am attaching some of my code in case they help you form the commands.
To load Key:
 const int keyByteLength = 6;
 SendBuff[0] = 0xFF; // CLA
 SendBuff[1] = 0x82; // INS: for stored key input
 SendBuff[2] = 0x20; // P1: same for all source types 
 SendBuff[3] = 0x01; // P2 : Memory location 0 or 1;
 SendBuff[4] = keyByteLength; // P3: Key Length
 for (int i = 0; i < _key.Length / 2; i++)
 {
     SendBuff[5 + i] = FromHexadecimalToByteArray(_key.Substring(i * 2, 2))[0];
 }

To Authentication:
 SendBuff[0] = 0xFF; // CLA
 SendBuff[1] = 0x86; // INS: for stored key input
 SendBuff[2] = 0x00; // P1: same for all source types 
 SendBuff[3] = 0x00; // P2 : Memory location;  P2: for stored key input
 SendBuff[4] = 0x05; // P3: for stored key input
 SendBuff[5] = 0x01; // Byte 1: version number
 SendBuff[6] = 0x00; // Byte 2
 SendBuff[7] = (byte)block; // Byte 3: sectore no. for stored key input
 SendBuff[8] = 0x60; // Byte 4 : Key A for stored key input
 SendBuff[9] = (byte)int.Parse("1"); // Byte 5 : Session key for non-volatile memory


While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

Sorry, I tried to add screenshots of the code, and it ended up like that. I have now modified it to include the code instead
